# HandleFunc being called twice

Tags: go

I am following a [simple web server example](http://thenewstack.io/building-a-web-server-in-go/) in Go.

I inserted a `log` statement so that the resulting code looks like below:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, "Hello world!")
    log.Println("hello.")
}

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/", hello)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", mux)
}
```

Problem is that whenever I load port 8000 in my web browser, this function is called twice. This is an issue because I intend to increment a counter on each page visit. With this behavior, counter gets incremented twice. OTOH, if I do `curl localhost:8000`, it is called only once.

I feel it's something really silly that I am missing here.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Just log the requests. You will realize that your browser also requests /favicon.ico.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon for more information.

Answer (score 22):

If you request from a service is fine, but if you test from a browser and is not the production intention you can do this in golang code for avoid browser load the favicon:

```
http.HandleFunc("/favicon.ico", doNothing)
```

And the function

```
func doNothing(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){}
```

For people voting negatives: this works, sorry for handle it with this code in an api that doesn't need favicon or whatever...

Answer (score 3):

As Didier says, it's your browser trying to load the favicon. You can prevent this by adding this code to the <head>:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo=">
```

Answer (score 3):

Building on what Didier Spezia said,
`"/"` is an example of a subtree path (because it ends in a trailing
slash). Another example would be something like `"/static/"`. Subtree path patterns are
matched (and the corresponding handler called) whenever the start of a request URL path
matches the subtree path. If it helps your understanding, you can think of subtree paths as
acting a bit like they have a wildcard at the end, like `"/**"` or `"/static/**" .`
This helps explain why the `"/"` pattern is acting as a catch-all. The pattern essentially
means match a single slash, followed by anything (or nothing at all).

To prevent that from happening,
just add a check in your hello handler like so

```
func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.URL.Path != "/" {
        http.NotFound(w, r)
        return
    }
    io.WriteString(w, "Hello world!")
    log.Println("hello.")
}
```