# Why this simple web server is called even number times?

Tags: http, go, server

I'm trying to learn Go web programming, and here is a simple web server: it prints out the times being called.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "net/http"
)

var calls int

// HelloWorld print the times being called.
func HelloWorld(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    calls++
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "You've called me %d times", calls)
}

func main() {
  fmt.Printf("Started server at http://localhost%v.\n", 5000)
  http.HandleFunc("/", HelloWorld)
  http.ListenAndServe(":5000", nil)
}
```

When I refresh the page, I got:

```
You've called me 1 times
You've called me 3 times
You've called me 5 times
....
```

Question: Why it is 1, 3, 5 times, rather than 1,2,3...? What's the order of the function `HelloWorld` being called?

Comment: print the request uri to see additional requests sent from your browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HandleFunc being called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33432192/handlefunc-being-called-twice)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is because every incoming request is routed to your `HelloWorld()` handler function, and the browser makes multiple calls under the hood, specifically to `/favicon.ico`.

And since your web server does not send back a valid favicon, it will request it again when you refresh the page in the browser.

Try it with Chrome: open the Developer tools (<kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+I</kbd>), and choose the "Network" tab. Hit refresh, and you will see 2 new entries:

```
Name          Status   Type
--------------------------------------------------------
localhost     200      document
favicon.ico   200      text/plain
```

Since your counter starts with `0` (default value for type `int`), you increment it once and you send back `1`. Then the request for `favicon.ico` increments it again (`2`), but the result is not displayed. Then if you refresh, it gets incremented again to `3` and you send that back, etc.

Also note that multiple goroutines can serve requests concurrently, so your solution has a race. You should synchronize access to the `calls` variable, or use the [`sync/atomic`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/) package to increment the counter safely, for example:

```
var calls int64

func HelloWorld(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    count := atomic.AddInt64(&calls, 1)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "You've called me %d times", count)
}
```

A simple "fix" to achieve what you want would be to check the request path, and if it is not the root `"/"`, don't increment, e.g.:

```
func HelloWorld(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.URL.Path != "/" {
        return
    }
    count := atomic.AddInt64(&calls, 1)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "You've called me %d times", count)
}
```

You may also choose to only exclude requests for `favicon.ico`, e.g.:

```
if r.URL.Path == "/favicon.ico" {
    return
}
```