# Can't get textarea value

Tags: html, forms, go, textarea, return-value

I'm trying to get the textarea value from a HTML form with Go, but it always returns as  blank/null.

HTML form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/tickets/" name="ticketForm"> 
 <textarea rows="3" cols="50" class="form-control" name="ticketDescription" id="ticketDescription" form="ticketForm" required> </textarea>
   </form>
```

Golang method to capture form data:

```
inputDescription := r.PostFormValue("ticketDescription")
```

If I choose ' input="text" ', for example, it gives me the value. It's just from textarea that goes with blank/null. I've used "fmt.Println(inputDescription)" just to see if Go is retrieving the value, and it goes as a blank value too.

Answer (score 2):

The `form` attribute of `<textarea>` must be the **`id`** attribute of a `<form>`, not `name`. Also, `form` is not necessary if the `<textarea>` is inside the `<form>`.

Since in your example your `<form>` has no `id` attribute and you provided `form` for your `<textarea>`, its value will not be sent when the form is submitted.

So do it like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="/tickets/" name="ticketForm"> 
  <textarea name="ticketDescription" id="ticketDescription" required> </textarea>
</form>
```

Or:

```
<form method="POST" action="/tickets/" id="ticketForm"> 
</form>

<textarea name="ticketDescription" id="ticketDescription"
    form="ticketForm" required> </textarea>
```

Also don't forget that in your handler you must call [`Request.ParseForm()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ParseForm) before you can access form values ([`Request.Form`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.Form)), or use [`Request.FormValue()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormValue) or [`Request.PostFormValue()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.PostFormValue) (which call `Request.Parseform()` if necessary).

Comment: Icza, thanks for the tip, but it didn't work out, I'm still getting blank value passing the ID as "ticketDescription". Maybe it's the way that I'm getting the data in Go code (?), I believe.

Comment: @ViniciusMocci Have you called `Request.ParseForm()` prior?

Comment: I'm using like this:

if err := r.ParseForm(); err != nil {
   fmt.Fprintf(w, "ParseForm() err: %v", err)
   return
  }

Comment: @ViniciusMocci I've tried the code I posted in my answer, and it works for me. If it doesn't work for you, please post all your code ([mcve]).

Comment: @ViniciusMocci Also please note that your browser might make multiple calls, to get `/favicon.ico`. If that ends up at your form handler, that request obviously won't contain the submitted form. For details, see [Why this simple web server is called even number times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35550189/why-this-simple-web-server-is-called-even-number-times/35550225#35550225)

Answer (score 0):

For those who @icza answer didn't work you might have missed `required` keyword. In my case only this keyword made a difference.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34263896)