# Go simple counter using channel

Tags: go

I am trying the program in [this](https://youtu.be/zJd7Dvg3XCk?list=PLoILbKo9rG3skRCj37Kn5Zj803hhiuRK6&t=1465) tutorial which basically starts a server and prints the counter value in the html tags. When I run the program the output I expect is values being printed from 0,1,2... so on but the output comes out to be 0,2,4,6,8,10...etc. I am unable to understand why this is happening. Please advice as the instructor said that the write to channel happens when there is a reader present so why is it leading to values being skipped.

Below is my source code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type nextChan chan int 

func(ch nextChan) handle(writer http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request){
    fmt.Fprintf(writer,"<h1> Counter value is %d </h1>",<-ch)
}

func counter(ch chan <-int){
    for i:=0; ;i++{
        ch <- i
    }
}

func main(){
    var nextId nextChan = make(chan int)
    go counter(nextId)
    http.HandleFunc("/",nextId.handle)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080",nil))
}
```

Output is:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Make your handler respond to GET requests only. The browser is probably first sending an OPTION request, and then a GET request, causing you to pull from the channel twice.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69445338/5728991

Comment: @BurakSerdar I tried adding logs and it does call my handler function twice per request. Could you tell how to respond to GET requests only? I am new to golang.

Comment: @Shivam...: `if req.Method == http.MethodGet`? favicon requests are also `GET` however.

Comment: @JimB Yes it wasn't working with checking request method. I did it the way it's mentioned in the link shared shared by Cerise above and it fixed it. I just tried matching the request URL.

Answer (score 0):

I added one check for `req.URL.Path`.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type nextChan chan int

func (ch nextChan) handle(writer http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    // Added these lines
    if req.URL.Path != "/" {
        http.NotFound(writer, req)
        return
    }

    fmt.Fprintf(writer, "<h1> Counter value is %d </h1>", <-ch)
}

func counter(ch chan<- int) {
    for i := 0; ; i++ {
        ch <- i
    }
}

func main() {
    var nextId nextChan = make(chan int)
    go counter(nextId)
    http.HandleFunc("/", nextId.handle)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```